# Resizing a numpy array in C with ctypes

Tags: python, numpy, ctypes

I am passing a numpy `ndarray` to a C function using ctypes:

```
lib = np.ctypeslib.load_library('library', 'path/to/library.so')
lib.function.argtypes = [ numpy.ctypeslib.ndpointer(ndim=1, dtype=numpy.float64, flags='C,A,W') ]
lib.function.restype = None

arr = numpy.zeros((10), dtype=numpy.float64)
lib.function(arr)
```

With the following C function:

```
void function(double *arr)
{
    arr = (double *) realloc(arr, 20 * sizeof(double));
}
```

However, the array remains the original size. Is there a simple way to allow the numpy array to change size when using `numpy.ctypeslib.ndpointer`?